# MySQL query to find the customers who have placed orders on consecutive days

Tags: mysql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to get the ids of the customers who have placed orders on consecutive days. The table is created as follows:

```
create table orders(
  orderid INT,
  orderdate date,
  customerid int
);
```

The values:

```
insert into orders (orderid, orderdate, customerid)
values(1,'2023-06-20',1),
    (2, '2023-06-21', 2),
    (3, '2023-06-22', 3),
    (4, '2023-06-22', 1),
    (5, '2023-06-23', 3),
    (6, '2023-06-22', 1),
    (7, '2023-06-26', 4),
    (8, '2023-06-27', 4),
    (9, '2023-06-29', 4),
    (10, '2023-06-29', 5),
    (11, '2023-06-30', 5),
    (12, '2023-06-28', 5),
    (13, '2023-06-25', 4),
    (14, '2023-06-24', 4),
    (15, '2023-06-30', 4);
```

The code that I wrote gave the output if ids with orders consecutive days but left the ids of customers who had a gap in their order despite having more number of orders before the gap actually occurred.
The code that I wrote:

```
with t1 as(
select customerid, orderdate,
case when lead(orderdate) over (partition by customerid order by orderdate) is null then 1
else abs(orderdate - lead(orderdate) over (partition by customerid order by orderdate)) end as gap
from orders)
select customerid, sum(gap) as consecutive
from t1
where gap>0
group by customerid
having count(*)=sum(gap) and count(*)>1;
```

The output:

```
+------------+------------------+
| customerid | consecutive_days |
+------------+------------------+
|          3 |                2 |
|          5 |                3 |
+------------+------------------+
```

The output I would want:

```
+------------+------------------+
| customerid | consecutive_days |
+------------+------------------+
|          3 |                2 |
|          4 |                4 |
|          4 |                2 |
|          5 |                3 |
+------------+------------------+
```

Since customer with customerid 4 has ordered from 2023-06-24 to 2023-06-27. The next order from the same customer is on 2023-06-29 and 2023-06-30 hence not continuous and should occur as a separate row.

Edit: The orders placed must be on consecutive days, irrespective of the number of orders placed on a single day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an other solution to resolve this gaps and islands, it can be resolved by calculating the difference between row numbers (`DENSE_RANK` is used because various customers may place orders on the same day) , which assigns a unique identifier to each sequence of consecutive orders for a customer :

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    *, DENSE_RANK() over(ORDER BY orderdate) - DENSE_RANK() over (PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY orderdate) as grp
  FROM orders
)
SELECT customerid, COUNT(DISTINCT orderdate) AS consecutive_days 
FROM cte
WHERE grp > 0
GROUP BY customerid, grp
HAVING consecutive_days > 1;
```

Results :

```
customerid  consecutive_days
3           2
4           4
4           2
5           3
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/L-SrNzTI)

Comment: This returns incorrect results if there is a gap in the sequence of order dates - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/m1GwaDjJ). This may not be a likely scenario, but possible.

Comment: Good catch @user1191247, This can be resolved by just excluding those where the difference is zero.

Comment: You didn't take my recent edit https://dbfiddle.uk/pnv9F2ur, However, I suspect that in certain scenarios, my solution might not get correct data.

Comment: You are right! I missed that. But I think you missed the point anyway - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xEasSYgt).

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical [gaps and islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+gaps-and-islands) problem and here is one way of getting your desired result:

```sql
SELECT customerid, COUNT(DISTINCT orderdate) AS consecutive_days
FROM (
    SELECT *, orderdate - INTERVAL DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY orderdate) DAY AS grp
    FROM orders
) AS order_groups
GROUP BY customerid, grp
HAVING consecutive_days > 1;
```

Outputs:

| customerid | consecutive_days |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qBUoYEzR).

If you look at the result of the derived table you can see that by subtracting the DENSE_RANK from the orderdate we create a value we can use for grouping.

| orderid | orderdate | customerid | grp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-20 | 1 | 2023-06-19 |
| 4 | 2023-06-22 | 1 | 2023-06-20 |
| 6 | 2023-06-22 | 1 | 2023-06-20 |
| 2 | 2023-06-21 | 2 | 2023-06-20 |
| 3 | 2023-06-22 | 3 | 2023-06-21 |
| 5 | 2023-06-23 | 3 | 2023-06-21 |
| 14 | 2023-06-24 | 4 | 2023-06-23 |
| 13 | 2023-06-25 | 4 | 2023-06-23 |
| 7 | 2023-06-26 | 4 | 2023-06-23 |
| 8 | 2023-06-27 | 4 | 2023-06-23 |
| 9 | 2023-06-29 | 4 | 2023-06-24 |
| 15 | 2023-06-30 | 4 | 2023-06-24 |
| 12 | 2023-06-28 | 5 | 2023-06-27 |
| 10 | 2023-06-29 | 5 | 2023-06-27 |
| 11 | 2023-06-30 | 5 | 2023-06-27 |

Note that I have used DENSE_RANK, instead of the more typical ROW_NUMBER, to handle customers placing multiple orders on the same day.

Answer (score -1):

It really depends on yxour table size.
If you only have a couple hundred orders, and O=N² is viable, go with something as simple as

```
SELECT DISTINCT o1.customerid
FROM orders o1
JOIN orders o2 ON o1.customerid = o2.customerid
AND DATEDIFF(o1.orderdate, o2.orderdate) = 1;
```

For performance, put a single index over both customerid and orderdate.

The **best** way, though somewhat complex, are the [MySQL LEAD and LAG functions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-lead-and-lag-function/).

Comment: This does not produce OP's required output